# Unique Combinations in a list of k,v tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, lambda, apache-spark, tuples

I have a list of various combos of items in tuples

`example = [(1,2), (2,1), (1,1), (1,1), (2,1), (2,3,1), (1,2,3)]`

I wish to group and count by unique combinations

yielding the result

`result = [((1,2), 3), ((1,1), 2), ((2,3,1), 2)]`

It is **not** important that the order is maintained or which permutation of the combination is preserved but it is **very** important that operation be done with a **lambda function** and the output format be still a list of tuples as above because I will be working with a spark RDD object

My code currently counts patterns taken from a data set using

`RDD = sc.parallelize(example)
result = RDD.map(lambda(y):(y, 1))\
.reduceByKey(add)\
.collect()
print result`

I need another `.map` command that will add account for different permutations as explained above

Comment: Does result order matter?

Comment: order does not matter

Comment: What makes  you think that any use of lambda is faster than a simple loop? It's quite the opposite, at least, in Python.

Comment: I need it to be done using a lambda function because I am using is with a spark RDD and I REALLY don't understand how those things work, so I need to be very careful about the data type I'm passing I'll try and update the question once more

Comment: Sounds like an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You seem to need a map-reduce kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem, but it was difficult to understand what I was really looking for I used

```
example = [(1,2), (1,1,1), (1,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,4), (2,3,1), (1,2,3)]
RDD = sc.parallelize(example)
result = RDD.map(lambda x: list(set(x)))\
            .filter(lambda x: len(x)>1)\
            .map(lambda(x):(tuple(x), 1))\
            .reduceByKey(add)\
            .collect()
print result
```

which also eliminated simply repeated values such as (1,1) and (1,1,1) which was of added benefit to me

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `OrderedDict` to crate an ordered dictionary based on  sorted case of its items :

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict()
>>> for i in example:
...   d.setdefault(tuple(sorted(i)),i)
... 
('a', 'b')
('a', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a')
('a', 'b')
('c', 'd')
('b', 'c', 'a')
('b', 'c', 'a')
>>> d
OrderedDict([(('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b')), (('a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'a')), (('a', 'a'), ('a', 'a')), (('c', 'd'), ('c', 'd')), (('a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'))])
>>> d.values()
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a'), ('c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'a')]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `d.setdefault(tuple(sorted(i)), i)` be enough?

Comment: Or even `d.setdefault(frozenset(i), i)`.

Comment: @bereal Yes that's a better idea!

Answer (score 1):

How about this: maintain a set that contains the sorted form of each item you've already seen. Only add an item to the result list if you haven't seen its sorted form already.

```
example = [ ('a','b'), ('a','a','a'), ('a','a'), ('b','a'), ('c', 'd'), ('b','c','a'), ('a','b','c') ]
result = []
seen = set()
for item in example:
    sorted_form = tuple(sorted(item))
    if sorted_form not in seen:
        result.append(item)
        seen.add(sorted_form)
print result
```

Result:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a'), ('c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'a')]
```

Comment: Beat me to it - This is how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a lambda function, try the following:

```
lambda x, y=OrderedDict(): [a for a in x if y.setdefault(tuple(sorted(a)), a) and False] or y.values()
```

You can use this lambda function like so:

```
uniquify = lambda x, y=OrderedDict(): [a for a in x if y.setdefault(tuple(sorted(a)), a) and False] or y.values()
result = uniquify(example)
```

Obviously, this sacrifices readability over the other answers.  It is basically doing the same thing as Kasramvd's answer, in a single ugly line.

Comment: Sorry I am really new to python could you show me how this would take in my list `example`

Comment: You would first set a variable to the lambda function like this: `uniquify = lambda x, y=OrderedDict(): [a for a in x if y.setdefault(tuple(sorted(a)), a) and False] or y.values()`.  Then, call the function with your list as an argument like this: `result = uniquify(example)`.  I've updated my answer to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar as the sorted dict.

```
from itertools import groupby
ex = [(1,2,3), (3,2,1), (1,1), (2,1), (1,2), (3,2), (2,3,1)]
f = lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)) as key
[tuple(k) for k, _ in groupby(sorted(ex, key=f), key=f)]
```

The nice thing is that you can get which are tuples are of the same combination:

```
In [16]: example = [ ('a','b'), ('a','a','a'), ('a','a'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('b','a'), ('c', 'd'), ('b','c','a'), ('a','b','c') ]
In [17]: for k, grpr in groupby(sorted(example, key=lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))), key=lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))):
    print k, list(grpr)
   ....:     
('a', 'a') [('a', 'a')]
('a', 'a', 'a') [('a', 'a', 'a')]
('a', 'a', 'a', 'a') [('a', 'a', 'a', 'a')]
('a', 'b') [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]
('a', 'b', 'c') [('b', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
('c', 'd') [('c', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you actually seem to need based on the comments, is map-reduce. I don't have Spark installed, but according to the docs (see [transformations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations)) this must be like this:

```
data.map(lambda i: (frozenset(i), i)).reduceByKey(lambda _, i : i)
```

This however will return `(b, a)` if your dataset has `(a, b), (b, a)` in that order.

Comment: I just updated the question to be clearer hopefully that helps

Comment: yup you were right it was an x, y thing and i solved it using a similar method what is protocol for this should I post my solution or should I delete my question? thanks again for all the help I wouldn't have solved it without these suggestions

Comment: @PeterDoro you [cannot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow) delete a question with upvoted answers. You can provide your own answer and accept it, so that people see that the topic is closed.